# Can I start another application(startup Redis Cache server) from inside of another application(Spring boot or Micronaut application)?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, micronaut

I want to use a Redis Caching service for my application to cache the results I will fetch from database. But I don't want to start the redis server manually each time. Can I somehow link Redis server to my application and start when I start my spring boot or Micronaut Project?

Comment: Is Docker / Docker Compose an option? In my opinion it´s not a good pattern to create such runtime dependencies hardwired in the dependent application code. What will happen if in the future you need 2 instances of your application (e.g. behind a Load Balancer?). What happens if you deploy to k8s?

Answer (score 0):

Implement CommandLineRunner, and it will execute when spring boot start.

```
public class ApplicationStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Application Started !!");
        logger.info("Redis Started !!");
    }
}
```

When shutdown add shutdown hook.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class SpringBootShutdownHookApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootShutdownHookApplication.class, args);
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void onExit() {
    log.info("Stoping springboot.");
    try {
      log.info("Stop redis")
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      log.error("", e);;
    }
    log.info("Stop redis success.");
  }
}
```